# Android emulator sdcard suddenly read-only(failing to mount?)

Tags: android

I've been using the android emulator with a mounted sdcard for a couple weeks now with no problem. Today I start my app and it crashes with a NullPointerException when my activity tries to access /mnt/sdcard. I check the DDMS file explorer and /mnt/sdcard seems to be empty. I try to push a file onto it but it's read-only, permissions are d---------. There are these two lines at the beginning of the logcat output:

```
D/Vold    (   29): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (   29): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
```

So I take it to mean that sdcard.img is suddenly failing to mount for some reason. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: make sure you have set permissions in your manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up a shell to the emulator

```
adb shell
```

Then type the following command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /sdcard
```

Does it work now?

Comment: I'd love to know why this stupid error takes place. I saw it on the 2.3.3 emulator just now

Comment: The bug is particularly nasty because each new emulator that you create still contains a read-only /sdcard

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would have forget to allocate memory for your sd-card. Go to Android virtual device manager and edit your emulator settings there set your sd card size to 512mb.It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered this problem for two days tracking.

1. I have forgotten to allocate memory for my sd-card. Go to Android virtual device manager and edit the emulator settings there set the sd card size to 128mb.
2. Check the AndroidMenifest.xml to set permissions
3. Use following code in the app to test file operation

   ```
   std::FILE* file = std::fopen("/sdcard/hello.txt","w+");
   if (file != NULL)    
   {
       std::fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
       std::fflush(file);
       std::fclose(file);
   }
   ```
4. Run the executable app in the emulator, 
   then use "adb shell ls /sdcard" to check if the file "hello.txt" is created already.

Answer (score 0):

I have on command `mount -o remount,rw /sdcard` outputted the message "Invalid argument." So
I moved the folder "android-sdk" so that there are no spaces in the path names.