# Android: Remount emulator SD card

Tags: android, android-emulator

The sd card on my emulator suddenly became read-only.
I've tried doing what this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174824/android-emulator-sdcard-suddenly-read-onlyfailing-to-mount) says, but I got the following message:
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory

Any one have any ideas as to what might be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Open a shell prompt to the emulator

adb shell

Then type this command:

mount -o remount,rw /sdcard

Comment: I'm still getting the same message