# android read video from windows

Tags: android, video

I want to test the behaviour of the mediaplayer I have implemented. This one doesn't read a stream from internet so I downloaded a mp4 video to test. But I cannot access my windows hard drive when using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). The command Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() gives me /storage/sdcard. So here is my question : how to access windows hard drive from android emulator ? And is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is **impossible**.

You can not access windows hard drive from android emulator directly.

Instead, If you are familiar with client-server programming, you can access localhost(10.0.2.2).

For now, if you want to load your mp4 file, push that file to emulator sdcard using DDMS.

- Inside Eclipse, window->Open perspective->DDMS.
- There you have a file explorer (if not seen, window->show view-> file explorer)
- Navigate to your sdcard (/storage/sdcard in your case)
- On top-right of the explorer, there are buttons for push/pull/remove files

Comment: Hey thanks Nizam. I did like this but I still have a read only error :/ 
[2013-10-25 15:47:01 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2013-10-25 15:47:02] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: Do you have sdcard created during creating emulator? See emulator details to see sdcard size using AVD manager

Comment: Yes it is. I saw a tuto saying i should modify the hardware options too but my avd screen doesn't have it

Comment: Well it seems I have no luck because I try to do this without success... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174824/android-emulator-sdcard-suddenly-read-onlyfailing-to-mount

Comment: Yup. but path differs. So, does that work after changing permission?

Comment: Which permissions ? I relaunched cmd in admin mode and re entered the command line but still this result : Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
which means it doens't work cause I tried to copy my file again :/
And on both sdcard folders...

Comment: Even if permissions are both set to lrwxrwxrwx

Comment: You missed the link in my comment? I was asking about changing the properties as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293973/2124004) link.

Comment: OK it seems to work now. I had seen this link earlier but I hadn't found Documents and settings. I finally localized avd and changed the permissions and now I did not have this error message. A big Thanks Nazim ;)

Comment: AH sorry Nizam. Nazim is the name of someone I know so your name made me think to him. And I had forgotten to put the problem as resolved, it's done now ;)